# Keyboard shortcut synchronization with Eclipse and IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

My time spent programming is split between what I do at work, and the programming I do at home in my spare time. At work, we use Vista machines and IntelliJ IDEA 8, whilst at home I use Mac OS X and Eclipse.

As you can imagine, my ability to easily switch between the two is getting more difficult as I find the keyboard shortcuts are different.

Is there a good way to quickly standardize the shortcuts for both Eclipse and IDEA? I see myself mostly using Eclipse in the future, so I would preferably like to switch in that direction.

If not, I'll do it manually (ughh).

Comment: Love you all! Had to switch to IntelliJ after 15 years or eclipse life, for work.. This was driving me nuts.. `Ctrl+~ -> Keymap -> Eclipse (macOS)` = **Heaven**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Odd, someone had the exact same [wish back in 2005](http://techgossip.blogspot.com/2005/01/intellij-eclipse-keymap.html)!

Intellij is supposed to have an [Eclipse Keymap](http://jetbrains.net/tracker/issue/IDEADEV-8565)

The [IntelliJ FAQ for eclipse user](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html) mentions:

> IntelliJ IDEA includes a bundled Eclipse keymap, so you can select it in Settings dialog, Keymap if you prefer using shortcuts you're accustomed to.

IntelliJ is supposed to have that Eclipse keymaps since the Demetra 6.0.5 version.
See their [Release Notes](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/release_notes605.html) from that (old) version.

Answer (score 35):

To get Eclipse Shortcuts, go to "Settings" and type "keymap".
Then select Eclipse on the list.

Answer (score 15):

Shortcut to use Eclipse shortcuts in IntelliJ Idea: 
Press ctrl+`(also have tilde~ on it, button at the left side of digit 1). Then press 3 (Keymap) and select 2 (Eclipse). Done!

Comment: clean and quick

Answer (score 10):

From the Settings dialog box -->  select Keymap --> select "eclipse" from keymap dropdown list. Have a look at below link for details:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Configure+Keymap

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't directly address your question, but IntelliJ's license allows you to run the application from home.  See their [faq](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/licensing_faq.html#q4).

That way you can use IntelliJ both at work, and at home.