# System.out.println() shortcut on Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know I can print `System.out.println()` with `"sout" + tab`.
Is there a way I can do it with `"Syso" + ctrl + space` like in eclipse?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-templates-2.html

Answer (score 343):

In Idea 17eap:

`sout`: Prints

```
System.out.println();
```

`soutm`:  Prints current class and method names to System.out

```
System.out.println("$CLASS_NAME$.$METHOD_NAME$");
```

`soutp`: Prints method parameter names and values to System.out

```
System.out.println($FORMAT$);
```

`soutv`: Prints a value to System.out

```
System.out.println("$EXPR_COPY$ = " + $EXPR$);
```

Comment: Is there any shortcut to call soutm for all functions in a file in one go? This is useful when you want to trace the function call flow with the help of logs.

Comment: Irrelevant answer regarding to question

Comment: One important thing to highlight is that Don't start with capital `S`. It should be small 's' then code suggestion will actually suggest  `sout` which on selection will do it.

Answer (score 70):

Yeah, you can do it. Just open Settings -> Live Templates. Create new one with `syso` as abbreviation and `System.out.println($END$);` as Template text.

Comment: This does not answer his wish to auto complete with ctrl+space.

Comment: Well, if he makes this setting, can't he just type `syso` and press `Tab` to complete the statement? We do something similar while defining the main method: we type in `psvm` and press `Tab` which automatically makes it `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: ctrl+space expands live templates as well

Comment: ctrl+space does not expand sout the same way tab does, it pulls up a menu with sout listed in it though--so pretty close (And that may be only because I turned on the Eclipse keymap).  Leo's answer helps

Comment: Along with this answer, make sure you select the below, 
"Applicable in Java: statement" by making the selection in the dropdown. 
Also, the Shortcut to use Eclipse shortcuts in IntelliJ Idea, follow the below steps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934543/3253199

Shortcut to use Eclipse shortcuts in IntelliJ Idea:
Press ctrl+`(also have tilde~ on it, button at the left side of digit 1). Then press 3 (Keymap) and select 2 (Eclipse). Done!

Comment: I added soup as the shortcut in live template in Java context, for System.out.print($END$);

Answer (score 56):

If you want to know all the shortcut in intellij hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. This shows all the shortcuts. For `System.out.println()` type `sout` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 16):

Open up Settings (By default is Alt + Ctrl + S) and search for Live Templates. In the upper part there's an option that says "By default expand with TAB" (TAB is the default), choose "Custom" and then hit "change" and add the keymap "ctrl+spacebar" to the option "Expand Live Template/Emmet Abbreviation".

Now you can hit ctrl + spacebar and expand the live templates. Now, to change it to "syso" instead of "sout", in the Live Templates option, theres a list of tons of options checked, go to "other" and expand it, there you wil find "sout", just rename it to "syso" and hit aply.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 6):

Type **`sout`** and press **Tab**, it will generate `System.out.println();`

Type **`sou`** and press **Tab**, It will generate  `System.out.printf("");`

Answer (score 4):

On MAC you can do `sout + return` or `⌘+j` (cmd+j) opens live template suggestions, enter `sout` to choose `System.out.println();`

Answer (score 3):

If using scala, try [`priv`](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Live+Templates) + <kbd>tab</kbd>