# How to make my own Code abbreviation in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

in IDEA ,I can type `sout`to represent `System.out.println();`and I want to know how to make my own code abbreviation.For example, alias `System.out.print();` to `soun`or any other names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *Live Template* in IntelliJ.

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Live Templates`. From there, select Java and on the right, you'll see a plus sign. By clicking it, you'll get a `1. Live Template` and that will get you a new abbreviation.

[image]

Name it `soun` and the text should be

```
System.out.print($END$);
```

Once you're done, make sure you've enabled that abbreviation by clicking the check box next to it.

---

The [docs of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html#pdtv) cover in detail what the syntax is for these templates.

> The `$END$` syntax indicates the position of the cursor when the code snippet is complete, and you can no longer press Tab to jump to the next variable.

There are more variables to look at as well and [other configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_configure) to do!

---

*Edit:* there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38992208/6577998) for this question, but it looks like it doesn't necessarily answer the question asked on that post, so that's why I've decided to post a dedicated answer (tackling the issue at hand).

Comment: `$END$`seems a special syntax ,what is this.Does the doc of IDEA introduce this in detail.Anyway,it's really a helpful answer

Comment: @Cyberlin I've updated my answer to explain what `$END$` means and I've provided some links! I'm glad this answer helps. If it answers your question, you can [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)