# Use custom Eclipse Neon keymaps in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Previously I have used eclipse neon and I customized keymaps (i.e. keybinding or shortcuts) for me. I saved the keymapping in csv file using Preferences -> keys -> Export CSV.

Now I upgraded my eclipse neon to eclipse oxygen and I want to use the same (custom key mapping I used previously in eclipse neon) keymapping in eclipse oxygen. But I do not see any option to import keymap (keybinding).

I know for other ides like intellij has keymap import system. I think probably eclipse also has same import system, but I am not finding it.

**Is there any way to import keymapping in eclipse oxygen from previous eclipse versions?**

N.B: I found quite similar question [Keyboard shortcut synchronization with Eclipse and IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472861/keyboard-shortcut-synchronization-with-eclipse-and-idea) and everybody is saying to change intellij keymaping to match with eclipse. And I do not want intellij keymapping in eclipse, what ***i want is to import customized keymapping to newer eclipse version from previous version***.

Comment: That is why I prefer to adapt my habits to the defaults of the ide. Sure, that sounds wrong - but it means that moving forward... Or just using the ide of a coworker is basically a no brainer...

Comment: Did you make a new workspace for Neon or did you point Neon at your old workspace? Typically the IDE customizations are hidden somewhere in the workspace folder as a text file and all you need to do is keep using the same workspace.  I'm not using Neon, so this could be broken, but I've been using the same workspace, or copies of it, since about 2001 and everything as just carried forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is still the same with the latest Eclipse version:

In ***File > Import/Export...: General > Preferences*** check the checkbox ***Keys Preferences*** and click ***Finish***

Keys preferences are stored in the workspace. Since Eclipse Oxygen you can also copy preferences to a new or to another workspace (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=130s)).

Via Eclipse Oomph you can synchronize preferences of different workspaces and since Eclipse Neon you can also store and synchronize them at Eclipse.org (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCsd681yo1c&t=25s)).